# Jenkins: Build Errors of Matrix Jobs in Emails?

Tags: configuration, jenkins, error-logging

We've set up a matrix job which builds our project for multiple configurations, namely Release and Debug. If one of these sub-jobs fails, the "Extended E-mail Notification" plugin sends out the following mail (${BUILD_LOG_REGEX}):

```
Build log lines matching "error," "failed," etc:
[...truncated 5 lines...]
Release completed with result FAILURE
[...truncated 1 lines...]
Debug completed with result FAILURE
Email was triggered for: Failure
Sending email for trigger: Failure
```

How do we get the actual error messages from the sub-jobs into the emails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a portion of the log in the mail, if not all, set the 'Extended E-mail Notification' to send a separate email for each job that failed, and use the **$BUILD_LOG** in the body of the message:

1. In the Multi-Configuration Job, the last parameter of the '*Editable
   Email Notification*' is '*Trigger for matrix projects*' - set it to
   '**Trigger for each configuration**'.
2. In the body of the message (below the '$DEFAULT_CONTENT' ) add the parameter **$BUILD_LOG**  to display the end of the build log
3. Assuming the log is in plain-text, change '*Content Type*' to **Plain Text**

For the list of built-in Jenkins parameters, go to this page:

http://[your-jenkins-server]/**env-vars.html**

Cheers